# I want to replace some part of screen with another screen in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

I want to toggle between completed and upcoming screen without reloading full screen just want to change the section under the button, refer image for understanding.
[image: Completed]

[image: Upcoming]

Comment: Show some code or what you have been trying to achieve this. We can't really help you without any code, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `TabNavigation` from react-navigation package you can check [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation). Also, you can change a part of a screen using a state in that screen something like this:

```
const Screen = () => {
  const [completed, setCompleted] = useState(true)

  return (
    ...
    { completed ? <Completed /> : <Upcoming /> }
    ...
  )
}
```

I hope you got the idea :)

Comment: hey Shayan, I tried to do it using ternary operators but it is giving an error of ReferenceError: useState is not defined. and after inserting import {  useState } from 'react'; in file its giving error of Error: Invalid hook call..      and about TabNavigator i read somewhere that tab navigator can only be used at the top or bottom of page.  can you help me with that ?

Comment: You should use ```useState``` in a react component, make sure that is correct and you can read the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) for exact implementation. For using ```TabNavigator``` read the docs and try figuring out the suitable way for you. I can't say anything about that, it depends on many things in your project.